# Central logging framework for Camunda workflow

Tags: bpmn, camunda

we are developing an application with Camunda which has multiple workflows.

Now for logging for the entire application i want to create a separate task which will be called from different points of each the workflows wherever needed.

It's like creating a centralized logging framework so that the log statements are standardized and follow our best practices.

Please let me know if this is a good idea to have a central logging task and if this possible even.

Looking for design ideas and dos and don'ts for this use case.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The process model should focus on the business logic. Logging is a purely technical thing and it is usually not a good idea to clutter the process model with tasks for this purpose. It also creates unnecessary audit information in the DB and makes the maintenance of the solution harder.

If you plan on call such a task from several point then you need a concept of reuse, so you might be thinking of call activities / sub processes, which may even increase the impact describe above.

I would first consider if you cannot change the log configuration to satisfy your needs.

If you need 'logging' on another level, then what you really want could be the tracking of state changes. For this Camunda's Spring eventing integration offers a generic way to publish state changes to a log sink without having to modify process models at all. Please see: https://docs.camunda.org/manual/latest/user-guide/spring-boot-integration/the-spring-event-bridge/

Here is an example application of the mechanism: https://github.com/rob2universe/camunda-slack (the target obviously doesn't have to be Slack)

Comment: we don't use java for coding, and there is a wrapper on camunda which we are not allowed to change much.

Comment: adding such a generic logging extension to the deployment is really something you should discuss with the peaple who own this layer. Cluttering the process model with logging related aspect leads to uglier, harder to maintain solution with technical disadvantages